# How do I move the Transaction Log for a database using sqlcmd/command line?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to move the transaction log for a database I have just created using aspnet_regsql.
Is it possible to move the transaction log using sqlcmd or any other command line tool?

Answer (score 6):

You can do so with the [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275464(SQL.80).aspx) command, but you still have to move the file manually.  The ALTER commands look like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDb SET OFFLINE;

ALTER DATABASE YourDb
MODIFY FILE (Name = YourDb_Log,
    Filename = 'g:\NewDir\YourDb.ldf')

<At this point, move the file in the filesystem>

ALTER DATABASE YourDb SET ONLINE;

RECONFIGURE
```

See this [SqlServer Central article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ALTER+DATABASE+MODIFY+FILE/67527/) for more information, and a complete script to execute the move.

Comment: you'll have to take the database offline to move the file & then bring it online again